# Your money is tight or Money is tight on you

Tags: grammar

(1) You don't have enough money this month.

(2) Money is tight on you this month.

(3) Your money is tight this month.

I am sure (1) is correct. Are the next two sentences also correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Your money is tight this month." makes sense, but this euphemism is most commonly phrased about money without a specifier, then applied to the relevant entity. It would be more common to say, "Money is tight this month." about one's own money, "Money is tight this month for you.", "Money is tight this month in that department." etc.

"Money is tight on you this month" is unusual.

Comment: @ansonguy You're quite welcome. FYI, "thank you" comments are actually discouraged here, but I appreciate it nonetheless. :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that "thank you" comments were not supported here. Thanks for pointing that out. I should say: Your explanation is clear and direct, making it easy for me to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: We might rather say "Money is tight **for** [somebody]".